# Can I Get More than the Top 20 on the top users page?

Tags: support, data-explorer, top-users

There are some tags that I like to check the stats for to get the top all-time answerers. Looking at the questions they answered and their answers is often very informative, and I like to RSS their blogs as well.

But the top users page only gives the Top 20. Is there any way to get more than 20?

---

Thank you Juha.

I've now created 2 queries:

1. [Top Askers for a Given Tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/154/top-askers-for-a-given-tag)
2. [Top Answerers for a Given Tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/155/top-answerers-for-a-given-tag)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could look into [Data Explorer](http://odata.stackexchange.com/). It allows you to execute arbitrary queries against data dumps. Data is up to 1 month old, but it may be enough for you.

Comment: Never knew about Data Explorer before. It will work. Don't know how I missed hearing about it.

Comment: @lkessler: Because it's practically brand new, that's how.

Comment: @mmyers: Well, I think it's great. I learned a lot just by being able to see how SO organizes its data and going through the interesting queries of others. It's a tremendous sandbox to play in.